# Dropdown menu not working in Flask python

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I am following this link - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp to create drop down bar in menu.

I make small changes to the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial;}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a, .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav" >
    <img src="static/logos/ds-LOGO.svg" alt="Deep Scopy"  style="width:20%; padding:10px 10px 10px 15px; float:left;" onContextMenu="return false;">  
<div style="float:right">
  <a href="{{ url_for('demo') }}" >HOME</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">PRODUCTS 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="{{ url_for('chest') }}">DS X-Ray</a>
      <a href="{{ url_for('endoscopy') }}">DS ENDOSCOPY</a>
      <a href="{{ url_for('brain') }}">DS MRI</a>
      <a href="{{ url_for('malaria') }}">DS MICRO</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="{{ url_for('contact') }}">CONTACT</a>


  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This works fine when I open this code in internet browser but when i load this html file using flask-python, the drop down is not working...

Cound you please help me to slove, thanks

Comment: Welcome to the community! Please provide your Python code. You should always try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Good luck with your project!

Comment: @Elisabeth Strunk, python program is very basic, I created the flask instance and used the render_template function to load this html file... I think the error is in this html file but I do not know what is the error

Comment: Dropdown works fine for me with the html you've prodied and a simple Flask server with single route 

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test.html')
```
the only thing I've removed were {{ url_for('') }} statements, not to define all the routes, so most probably the proble is not with the html you've provided

Comment: If you're html code is working before when it isn't served by you're flask server, then the issue could possibly be from you're python code itself, are you using templates? did you put the html and css in different files? it could be an issue with static files and templates etc...